# How do I remove all elements with a particular class name from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with elements representing products, which have the **cart-item** class.

```
<div id="cart">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Demostration Site</h1>

    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ol id="insert-zone" class="ui-droppable ui-sortable">
            <li class="placeholder" style="display: none;">Add your items here</li>
            <div class="item-container cart-item"></div>
            <div class="item-container cart-item"></div>
            <div class="item-container cart-item"></div>
            <div class="item-container cart-item"></div>
            <div class="item-container cart-item"></div>
            <div class="item-container cart-item"></div>
            <div class="item-container cart-item"></div>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to have a button that, upon being pressed, clears all items with class cart-item to get an empty cart. How can I do this?

Comment: Where's your JavaScript code so far? Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery: `$('#insert-zone').empty();`

Or if you don't want to clean it up completely:  `$('.cart-item').remove();`

Also you need a button. So:

```
$('#button-id').on('click', function() {
   $('.cart-item').remove();
});
```

Comment: +1 but I'd prefer `$('#insert-zone .cart-item').empty();` to make the intent clear.

Answer (score 3):

This will remove all the div elements that have class `cart-item` under `ol #insert-zone`:

```
var ol = document.getElementById('insert-zone');
var div = ol.getElementsByClassName('cart-item');

for(var i=0;i<div.length;i++)
   ol.removeChild(div[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple to do with jQuery

Here is an example I just whipped up: http://jsfiddle.net/anUqB/

HTML:

```
<div id="cart">
    <div class="item-container cart-item">item</div>
    <div class="item-container cart-item">item</div>
    <div class="item-container cart-item">item</div>
    <div class="item-container cart-item">item</div>
    <div class="item-container cart-item">item</div>
    <div class="item-container cart-item">item</div>
</div>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Java Script

```
$("#clear").click( function() { //When the button with id "clear" is pressed
    $(".cart-item").each( function() { // Find an iterate through each item with class "cart-item"
       $(this).remove(); // Remove the item
    });
});
```

Comment: @frenchie4111 +1 for a decent answer, though it's not optimal. Calling **remove()** on a collection of items removes each of those items, so **$(".cart-item").remove()** would remove every **cart-item** on its own.

Comment: I saw that after I posted. Figured I would leave this answer in case he ended up wanting to do something else with the elements (Like send ajax requests to remove the cookies or something)